# New Relic's pings not improving cold start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, appharbor, newrelic, cold-start

*There's a similar question about app harbor on StackOverflow, but the user didn't try to use new relic to overcome the problem.*

I deployed my ASP.NET MVC project on App Harbor. It's very easy to configure and you can even set automatic deployments from Git. However, as my website is still mainly used only by me, I was getting very long cold starts (over 15 secs). To avoid it, I installed New Relic. The idea was to simultaneously to monitor the application but also to create periodic pings that, according to "a lot of people", would drastically reduce the loading time.

It's not working. I have New Relic correctly pinging my application every minute, but I still get very long cold starts. For instance, 5 min ago, I've got a cold start of 16 seconds. 1 minute after, I got the page loaded in less than a second.

I know I could have used Pingdom or StillAlive to achieve the same result:
[How do I improve app performance on AppHarbor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242676/how-do-i-improve-app-performance-on-appharbor)

I wouldn't like to do it because I like New Relic and I don't want to have a lot of add-on's on app harbor as they will slow down my website. Do you have any idea what might be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with AppHarbor's setup. But if it's using IIS, the pinging is just keeping the application pool from reaching the idle timeout. But there the default IIS setting for the application pool to be recycled every 29 hours no matter the number of requests. And it's normally in the best interest to let it recycle once in a while, so working around it may not be in your best interest.

Your best bet is to reduce the number of things happening on application start. Precompiling your views is a good place to start. And heck, [Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow precompiles views to avoid the application start up cost](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/441948058470060033).